# Wrong definition of limit

Tags: calculus, limits

The problem is to show by example that the following statement about limit is wrong.

the number L is the limit of f(x) as x approaches c, if f(x) gets closer to L as x approaches c.

This definition looks OK to me but my textbook states that this statement is wrong, can you explain what is  am I missing?

Comment: $x^2$ gets closer to $-1$ as $x\to0$

Comment: @saulspatz so basically the problem is in the part "...f(x) gets closer to L..." which means that if distance between basically any number and f(x) decreases as x approaches c, then it is limit of f(x), and that's why -1 satisfy this definition, right?

Comment: @saulspatz so should the definition be replaced with: "if 'f(x) approaches L' as x approaches c, then only we can say that limit of f(x) as x approaches c is L"?

Comment: You could get more accurate by saying "if the distance between $f(x)$ and $L$ gets strictly smaller as the distance between $x$ and $c$ gets smaller, then $L$ is the limit..."

Comment: This is mathematically stylized in the formal definition of the limit $$\forall\varepsilon>0,\ \exists\delta>0\ \text{such that}\ 0<|x-c|<\delta\implies|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$$

Comment: No. $x^2$ gets strictly closer to $-1$ as $x\to0$.  The point is that $f(x)$ gets *arbitrarily* close to $L$ if $x$ is *sufficiently* close to $c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with this definition.

- The first one has been abundantly discussed in the comments, namely you can get closer to $L$ but with a gap that only decrease without becoming zero.

For $L$ to actually be a limit this gap must decrease *arbitrary small* (i.e. be eventually zero) as you get closer to $c$.

- The second issue is subtle, the wording let people think that the distance between $f(x)$ and $L$ should decrease as the distance between $x$ and $c$ decreases as well.

In fact with an actual limit, it is possible that $d(f(x),L)\searrow$ but it is also possible there are oscillations of $f(x)$ around $L$, it is just that the oscillations must decrease in amplitude as we get closer to $c$.

This is why we usually add the clause "when $x$ is *close enough* to $c$", note the difference with "as $x$ gets closer to $c$".

Answer (score 0):

The right way to say it with words : "you can get f(x) to be *arbitrarily* close to L, as x gets close enough to c"