# How does $x^2$ get closer to -1 as $x \to 0$

Tags: limits

This question comes from an exercise in Thomas' Calculus:

> **A wrong statement about limits** Show by example that the following
> statement is wrong.
>
> The number $L$ is the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $c$ if $f(x)$ gets closer to $L$ as $x$ approaches $c$.
>
> Explain why the function in your example does not have the given
> value of $L$ as a limit as $x \to c$.

The function given in the answers was $f(x)=x^2$ and it was said that $f(x)$ gets closer to $-1$ as $x \to 0$. The same thing has been stated in the comments of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3435671/wrong-definition-of-limit).

Based on my understanding of $x$ "approaches" $0$, I believe if by substituting values for $x$ which are closer to $0$ (i.e "approaching" $0$) we should get values of $f(x)$ closer to $-1$, thus disproving the statement. But unlike expected, $x^2$ does not get closer to $-1$ (Mathematically, it never can as product of two real numbers is always positive)

Note: This table has been generated through a computer program for demonstration purposes.

| x | f(x) |
| --- | --- |
| $0.10000000000000000555$ | $0.0100000000000000019428902930940239457414$ |
| $0.01000000000000000194$ | $0.0001000000000000000454497550705923458736$ |
| $0.00000001000000000000$ | $0.0000000000000001000000000000001088433435$ |
| $0.00000000001000000000$ | $0.0000000000000000000001000000000000001224$ |
| $0.00000000000100000000$ | $0.0000000000000000000000010000000000000012$ |
| $0.00000000000000000001$ | $0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000001$ |
| $-0.10000000000000000555$ | $0.0100000000000000019428902930940239457414$ |
| $-0.01000000000000000194$ | $0.0001000000000000000454497550705923458736$ |
| $-0.00000001000000000000$ | $0.0000000000000001000000000000001088433435$ |
| $-0.00000000001000000000$ | $0.0000000000000000000001000000000000001224$ |
| $-0.00000000000100000000$ | $0.0000000000000000000000010000000000000012$ |
| $-0.00000000000000000001$ | $0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000001$ |

I even tried the graphical approach - here is a graph I have plotted ($f(x)$ in green, $y=x-1$, $y=-x-1$ in black):

[image: Graph plotted on GeoGebra 5]

If $f(x)$ were to approach $-1$, then the lines $y=x$ and $y=(-x)$ should have been tangents to $y=x^2$, which it isn't.

So, where am I going wrong? Have I misunderstood the concept of approaching?

Comment: It gets literally closer to $-1$, but not ARBITRARILY as close as you could ever desire.  That's the difference.

Comment: For example, $1^2$ is farther from $-1$ than $0^2$. Trying to read more into the word "approaching" than what is written in an English dictionary won't get you closer to understanding limits.

Comment: So here we are referring to the English word "approaching", which just means getting closer. Just to check my understanding, this statement could be disproved using the function f(x)=|x| for the same reasons. Am I right?

Comment: This is the point of the exercise:  to understand that one needs a precise mathematical definition to speak of limits correctly.

Comment: @Randall and John: Got it! Thank you so much!

Comment: The problem with the statement lies not the meaning of "approaching" but in the meaning of "gets closer to". I consider "approaching" something in a mathematical context to mean getting arbitrarily close to it, but the statement merely uses "gets closer to" for the behaviour of f(x) towards L, which is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Here, approaching refers to the English word, which is defined as "coming nearer in distance or time". As $0^2=0$ is closer to $-1$ than $1^2=1$, according to the dictionary definition, f(x) is approaching $-1$. Likewise, it can be said f(x) is approaching $-2$ too!

Comment: Here, I would use "gets closer" as in the OP.  Then we do not confuse it with the mathematical meaning of "approach".